# How do I associate all unknown file types with notepad++?

Tags: windows, notepad++, file-association

I work alot with billing and files the bank etc. send me files that have date extensions or some counter as an extension:

eg file1.20110315 or file2.123

So the extension changes every time I receive another file.

Is it possible to associate all file types that end in numbers or if not any unknown file types with notepad(++)?

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 10):

You can edit the `openas` command of the `Unknown` type, i.e.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\openas\command.
```

Alternatively, you can add a new command if you want to keep the Open As command.

If you want to make Open with Notepad++ the default, edit the default value of the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell` subkey.

Comment: Yup, this is the correct method to register *unknown* filetypes. The `HKCR\*` key is for *all* files.

For the record, I too would not recommend setting a text-editor as the default *open* command for all or unknown files. Instead, set a hex-editor as the default open command, and add a separate *“notepad”* command for the text-editor.

Comment: To get this working I changed HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\openas\command\\(Default) to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %1   . I also had to rename HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\openas\command\DelegateExecute to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\openas\command\DelegateExecuteBackup

Answer (score 7):

As the accepted answer isn't explicit in how to do this, here's how I got it to work:

1. Open `regedit.exe` as administrator
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell`
3. Right-click `shell` -> New -> Key -> "npp"
4. Right-click `npp` -> New -> Key -> "command"
5. Edit the Default value of `npp\command` to be `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe "%V"` or `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%V"` depending on where you installed npp.
   (The %V passes the file path to the program).

Comment: tried, doesnt work

Comment: after that I think you have to set 'npp' at default value for shell

Answer (score 1):

The article [Add "Open with Notepad" to the Context Menu for All Files](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/) describes how to do something similar to what you want, and could easily be changed for use notepad++.

I'm not aware of a way to do it for all numeric extensions.

Answer (score -1):

You can assign the file type "*" in the registry with Notepad++. But I won't reccomend this, since all files, even binary ones, dll's and so on will be associated then.

Comment: this is not what have been asked.

Comment: But it is a relevant answer, and a possible solution.