# Open unknown filetypes in text editor?

Tags: windows-7, text-editors

Is there a way to open files with unknown extensions, or no extension, in a text editor by default?

I'm mostly interested in doing this on Windows 7, but it would be nice to know how in Mac/Linux too.

Comment: See the comment I posted on the first answer for this question http://superuser.com/questions/257941/how-do-i-associate-all-unknown-file-types-with-notepad

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft has a knowledge base article for just this situation:

[KB236014](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236014) - "INFO: Shell Extensions for File Names with No File Extension"

Blurb:

> For example, to associate a program (for example, Notepad.exe) to open all files with no extension, use the following registry keys:
>
> `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.]`
> `@=""`
>
> `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\shell]`
>
> `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\shell\open]`
>
> `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.\shell\open\command]`
> `@="<path to notepad.exe> %1"`

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to get back to you on this... I tried saving it as a .reg and executing it but that didn't seem to help. Is there a special trick to it? Thanks! This sounds perfect

Answer (score -1):

Linux doesn't consider file extensions as important as Windows does. Nevertheless it's usually a guide to the type of contents.

When I wish to open a file (I'm using Linux Mint 11) I right-click on the name and choose **Open With**, then select a text editor (like **gedit**) from the list of Applications.

I tend to use this approach in Windows (XP) too, but I choose **Send to ...**

That means I have to put a shortcut to my favourite text editor in the appropriate place. I've no idea how Windows 7 handles this.