# Open all unknown extensions with notepad++

Tags: windows-10, notepad++

I want to make all unknown files open using notepad++ by default (without having to select notepad after windows asks). I found this thread, but the answers were not very helpful.

[How do I associate all unknown file types with notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/257941/how-do-i-associate-all-unknown-file-types-with-notepad)

How would one accomplish this?

Comment: I think this is useful enough that it warrants having the solution in an actual answer instead of having it hidden away in the comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I associate all unknown file types with notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/257941/how-do-i-associate-all-unknown-file-types-with-notepad)

Comment: I already linked that question in the question body, but none of the answers actually work. There is a comment that works, but people who see the question will look at the answers and find that they do not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open registry editor as administrator.
- Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\openas\command`

You can can copy paste this to the address bar below File-Edit etc.

- Double click on `(Default)`
- Paste the following command `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe "%V"`
- Click OK
- Right click DelegateExecute->Rename
- Change the name to `DelegateBackup`

Now unknown files should launch using notepad++

This solution is thanks to "rob" in the comments: [How do I associate all unknown file types with notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/257941/how-do-i-associate-all-unknown-file-types-with-notepad).

Comment: This works. As a note, if you have installed 64 bit Notepad++ then of course you need to remove the " (x86)". This should be obvious, but I screwed this up and have been wondering why this wasn't working for me on my new PC.

Comment: It works, but it seems like it replaces "Open With" by "Open With Notepad++", this means that it's harder to assign a particular file to another program. A better solution would be: Open with Notepad++ on double click, but still keep the default behavior of "Open With" when using the right click menu (To allow picking a different app and checking "Always open with that app"), btw, to revert, just rename `DelegateBackup` to `DelegateExecute`